# How to make the direction of the carousel vertical in ipywidgets?

Tags: jupyter, ipywidgets

```
from ipywidgets import Layout, Button, VBox, Label

item_layout = Layout(height='100px', min_width='40px')
items = [Button(layout=item_layout, description=str(i), button_style='warning') for i in range(40)]
box_layout = Layout(overflow='scroll hidden',
                    border='3px solid black',
                    width='500px',
                    height='',
                    flex_flow='row',
                    display='flex')
carousel = Box(children=items, layout=box_layout)
VBox([Label('Scroll horizontally:'), carousel])
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Ir3Q.png)

expected result:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZK5kr.png)

I tried to change flex_flow from row to column
Here is the result:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1YlYw.png)

Answer (score 0):

Just use `overflow_y` instead `overflow`.

```
from ipywidgets import Layout, Button, VBox, Label, Box

item_layout = Layout(min_height="40px", min_width="100px")
items = [Button(layout=item_layout, description=str(i), button_style="warning") for i in range(40)]
box_layout = Layout(
    overflow_y="scroll hidden",
    border="3px solid black",
    align_items="flex-start",
    width="fit-content",
    height="500px",
    flex_flow="column",
    display="flex",
)

carousel = Box(children=items, layout=box_layout)
VBox([Label("Scroll vertically:"), carousel])
```